# Not able to create key vault being a Global Admin

Tags: azure-resource-group, azure-security

I am trying to create Azure Key vault via Portal. While I'm selecting create a keyvault option in Azure Portal, I am getting error like below on Basics tab:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6noB.png)

I am the Global Admin of my account. It's saying the resource group is read-only. How to change it?

How to get rid of this error? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: post error here. do not attach from other website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The error usually occurs if read-only lock on your resource group is enabled.***

To resolve the error, you need to delete the lock, but it requires **`Owner`** or **`User Access Administrator`** roles.

As you already have **`Global Admin`** role, you can [**elevate the access**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin#elevate-access-for-a-global-administrator) by enabling the option like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Properties -> Access management for Azure resources -> Yes -> Save*

[image]

**After elevating the access, you can delete the lock like below:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Resource Groups -> Your Resource Group -> Locks*

[image]

**After deleting the locks, you will be able to create Key vault successfully.**